# Spark 2.3.0 SQL unable insert data into hive hbase table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hbase

Use Spark 2.3 thriftserver integrated with hive 2.2.0. running from spark beeline. Try to insert data into hive hbase table (a hive table with hbase as storage). Insert into hive native table is ok. When inserting into hive hbase table, it throws the following exception:

> ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveOutputFormat
>
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>          at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveOutputFormat
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveFileFormat$$anon$1.outputFormat$lzycompute(HiveFileFormat.scala:93)
>           k failed while writing rows.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
>        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveOutputFormat
>        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveFileFormat$$anon$1.outputFormat$lzycompute(HiveFileFormat.scala:93)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known hive issue. There are several pull requests addressing it but I haven't found an actual fix yet.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6628

Comment: I check this, seems the fix code is not commit into spark. The spark 2.3, 2.2 source code still use the bad one. also there some one said change the HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat to extend HiveOutputFormat, that one also not commit into the hive 2.2 or hive 2.3