# Class Cast Exception from HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat to HiveOutputFormat on Data Insert Into Table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hbase, apache-spark-sql

When I attempt to insert data into a table using Spark SQL with the intent of writing to HBase via Hive, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat cannot be cast to
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveOutputFormat
```

I'm using HBase 1.4.9, Hive 2.3.4, and Spark 2.4.0. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: seems like its issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679965/spark-2-3-0-sql-unable-insert-data-into-hive-hbase-table there is an outstanding [pull request]( https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18127) to be merged in to spark